# How to correctly change date and time in regex code inside python?

Tags: python, regex

I am a beginner to python and I have a log file which I need to take date time. I use regex for taking the 2 conditions but unfortunately my result is not as expected, this is the result I got:

```
 Date               Time       
 20170119        193739188+0900
```

log file:

```
20170119 193739188+0900 elim1td001p imapserv 58124 72559 139941478487808 Note;AcctBadPswd(50/6)
```

I would like to know that how to change the date and time format inside the regex code to have a better result? This is my regex code:

```
import re
from csv import writer
log_file = '/Users/kiya/Desktop/mysql/ipscan/ip.txt'
output_file = '/Users/kiya/Desktop/mysql/ipscan/output.csv'

name_to_check = 'MBX_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED'

with open(log_file,encoding="utf-8") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if name_to_check in line:
            username = re.search(r'(?<=userName=\[)(.*)(?=\],)', line)
            username = username.group()

            date = re.search('(?P<year>\d{4})(?P<month>\d{2})(?P<date>\d{2})', line)
            date = date.groups()

            time = re.search(r'(\d{9}\+\d{4})', line)
            time = time.group()

            ip = re.search(
                r'(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])',
                line)
            ip = ip.group()

            with open(output_file, 'w') as outfile:
            csv_writer = writer(outfile)
            csv_writer.writerow(["Username","Date","Time","Ip_address"])
            csv_writer.writerow([username,date,time,ip])
```

I would like the result to be as:

```
Date: 2017-01-09
Time: 01:15:30 (like)
```

Comment: You just want the time to be the string 'UTC'?

Comment: @chrisz not the string UTC, but in UTC format, like: 11:30:45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re` and `datetime` module.

**Demo:**

```
import re
import datetime
s = "20170119 193739188+0900 elim1td001p imapserv 58124 72559 139941478487808 Note;AcctBadPswd(50/6)"
m = re.search("(?P<date>\d{8})\s+(?P<time>\d{9})\+(?P<zone>\d{4})", s)
if m:
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(m.group('date'), "%Y%m%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    time = datetime.datetime.strptime(m.group('time'), "%H%M%S%f").strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print(date)
    print(time)
```

**Output:**

```
2017-01-19
19:37:39
```

Comment: but when I try to write it into csv is date is not working

Comment: no error, when I do it to csv, the answer is not showing correctly, only it shows the date and time format from the log file

Comment: Try this `csvwriter.writerow([date,time])`

Answer (score 0):

Date Parsing can be done like shown below:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = r'20170119 193739188+0900 elim1td001p imapserv 58124 72559 139941478487808 Note;AcctBadPswd(50/6)'
>>>
>>> matchObj = re.search('(?P<year>\d{4})(?P<month>\d{2})(?P<date>\d{2})\s+(?P<hour>\d{2})(?P<min>\d{2})(?P<sec>\d{2})', line)
>>>
>>> matchObj.groups
<built-in method groups of _sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000021C1DF1CB20>
>>> matchObj.groups()
('2017', '01', '19', '19', '37', '39')
>>>
>>>
>>> print('Date: %s-%s-%s' % (matchObj.group('year'), matchObj.group('month'), matchObj.group('date')))
Date: 2017-01-19
>>>
```

Similarly, You can use for time.

```
>>>
>>> time = 'Time: {}:{}:{}'.format(matchObj.group('hour'), matchObj.group('min'), matchObj.group('sec'))
>>>
>>> time
'Time: 19:37:39'
>>>
```

Comment: when I try to write it into csv is date is not working .i updated my code please have a look